# How to use temporarySignedRoute() in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have this route in the `web.php`:

```
Route::get('/email/sent/{email}', function(){
        return view('auth.passwords.email_sent');
})->name('forgot-password.email.sent')->middleware(['signed']);
```

In a controller I am generating a temporary signed route using:

```
$url = URL::temporarySignedRoute('forgot-password.email.sent', now()->hours(1), ['email' => $email]);
```

How ever everytime I visit the route it returns `403 Forbidden`. But if I use `signedRoute()`:

```
$url = URL::signedRoute('forgot-password.email.sent', ['email' => $email]);
```

It works, I think the problem is with the generated timestamps but I am not really sure.

Has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: what do you think `now()->hours(1)` is doing?

Comment: I think it generates timestamps that indicates the route will expire in an hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`now()->hours(1)` sets the date to `now` except with the hour changed to the number passed, in your case 1, which is not what you want. And because 1 AM happens to be before the current time, the temporary route is already expired when you try to access it and you get a 403 error.

Try `now()->addHours(1)` instead.

In the future you could try to die & dump or log `now()->hours(1)` to check what's wrong with the date and time.

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-now here the now helper is described. `\Illuminate\Support\Carbon` is instantiated, which wraps `Carbon\Carbon`, which means you can see the available methods here: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/.

You could also use Carbon directly if you wanted.